# UPDATE query from OUTER JOINed tables or derived tables

Tags: database, ms-access

Is there any way in MS-Access to update a table where the data is coming from an outer joined dataset or a derived table?  I know how to do it in MSSQL, but in Access I always receive an "Operation must use updateable query" error.  The table being updated is updateable, the source data is not.  After reading up on the error, Microsoft tells me that the error is caused when the query would violate referential integrity.  I can assure this dataset will not.  This limitation is crippling when trying to update large datasets.   I also read that this can supposedly be remedied by enabling cascading updates.  If this relationship between my tables is defined in the query only, is this a possibility? So far writing the dataset to a temp table and then inner joining that to the update table is my only solution; that is incredibly clunky.  I would like to do something along the lines of this:

```
UPDATE Table1 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1=Table2.Field1
WHERE Table2.Field1 IS Null
SET Table1.Field1= Table2.Field2
```

or

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Field1, Field2
        FROM Table2, Table3 
        WHERE Field3=’Whatever’
    ) AS T2 ON Table1.Field1=T2.Field1
SET Table1.Field1= T2.Field2
```

Answer (score 2):

Update Queries are very problematic in Access as you've been finding out.

The temp table idea is sometimes your only option.

Sometimes using the DISTINCTROW declaration solves the problem (Query Properties -> Unique Records to 'Yes'), and is worth trying.

Another thing to try would be to use Aliases on your tables, this seems to help out the JET engine as well.

Comment: The reason Jet/ACE won't execute these is because the query optimizer can't tell what the result would be in terms of how many records would be updated. DISTINCTROW in some cases can take care of that problem, but not all (it won't fix the problem when you're trying to update to aggregated values from Sum(), etc.). I don't know that aliases can possible help the query optimizer. I'd be interested in hearing more about that suggestion.

Comment: Nothing seems to do it, aliases, distinctrow, even sub queries instead of derived tables. You can see the use of an alias on the second example - but to no avail.  ugh.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table3 
INNER JOIN 
(Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.uid = Table2.uid) 
ON 
(Table3.uid = Table2.uid) 
AND 
(Table3.uid = Table1.uid) 
SET 
Table2.field=NULL;
```

What I did is:
1. Created 3 tables
2. Establish relationships between them
3. And used the query builder to update a field in Table2.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  Unfortunately your solution uses inner joins and my question is about the other types of joins.  The dataset produced from your sql and from mine would be very very different.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem in the query logic. In your first example, you LEFT JOIN to Table2 on Field1, but then have

```
Table2.Field1 IS NULL
```

in the WHERE clause. So, this limits you to records where no JOIN could be made. But then you try and update Table 1 with data from Table2, despite there being no JOIN.

Perhaps you could explain what it is you are trying to do with this query?

Comment: Using a left join in this manner would limit the dataset to matching records.  The sql statement was only an example to illustrate the problem I am having is updating records where the read dataset has something other than an inner join.